# db-sync not syncing

Tags: cardano-db-sync

I've restored a [recent db-sync snapshot](https://update-cardano-mainnet.iohk.io/cardano-db-sync/index.html#13.1/) (I am running node 8.1.2). The restore was successful; I can run SQL queries against the default `cexplorer` database. However, there seems to be an issue when I begin running db-sync to sync the rest of the way.

For context, I am using the [Guild Operator's scripts](https://cardano-community.github.io/guild-operators/Build/dbsync/) (`.dbsync.sh -d`); the systemd service deploys successfully, but after several hours the (restored) database still appears not to be syncing, as evidenced when I run:

```
cexplorer=# select now () - max (time) as behind_by from block ;
       behind_by
------------------------
 5 days 22:44:28.094372
(1 row)
```

And after several minutes:

```
cexplorer=# select now () - max (time) as behind_by from block ;
       behind_by
------------------------
 5 days 22:58:38.184134
(1 row)
```

**The `behind_by` value keeps increasing**, so I assume the databse is not syncing.

Here are the log message(s) after running `tail -10f $CNODE_HOME/logs/dbsync.json`:

`{"app":[],"at":"2023-09-13T20:45:54.69Z","data":{"kind":"LogMessage","message":"Handling input offset 22100000"},"env":"<unknown>:00000","host":"","loc":null,"msg":"","ns":["db-sync-node"],"pid":"918006","sev":"Info","thread":"6"}`

Any ideas what could be wrong or what the log message means?

Comment: The reason why its not syncing will almost certainly be obvious if you look at the logs of both the `node` and `db-sync`.

Comment: I asked cause I'm definitely a noob.

I suspect it has something to do with the "Handling input offset" message, but not sure what it means.

Comment: Nothing to do with that message. That is an effect not a cause and it gives zero clue as to the actual cause.

Comment: so then which log files are you referring to?

Comment: The logs for the `node` and the logs for `db-sync`. One or the other should have the proper cause. I am not familiar with the Guild operator scripts so I am not sure where the log files are. Probably in `$CNODE_HOME`

Answer (score 1):

Few checkpoints for you before you even start:

1. Check status for services:
   sudo systemctl status cnode
   sudo systemctl status cnode-dbsync
2. Since you've used Guild-Ops scripts, you've already got [gLiveView](https://cardano-community.github.io/guild-operators/Scripts/gliveview/) installed in `$CNODE_HOME/scripts` folder. I assume you went through [documentation](https://cardano-community.github.io/guild-operators/Scripts/env/) to ensure you've updated variables in `env` file.
3. Before looking at dbsync, I'd first recommend you ensure your node is working and in sync - gLiveView gives a nice little overview to check status of your node.
4. All the logs are in $CNODE_HOME/logs folder, the node (by default) would be node0.json. So if any of the component isnt working, you'd need to check corresponding log file for the cause.